# R mlr - How does tuneThreshold work to tune the prediction threshold?

Tags: r, mlr

This is a cross-post from [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/446362/edit). I haven't had any luck posting questions related to the `mlr` package there so I thought I would try here.

I would like to tune the threshold for the following classification task using `tuneThreshold` in conjunction with a learner parameter.

I first tried to tune the threshold during the tuning of the learner by setting `makeTuneControlRandom(..., tune.threshold = TRUE)`:

```
library(ElemStatLearn)
library(mlr)
data(spam)
load_all()

task = makeClassifTask(data = spam, target = "spam")
lrn1 = makeLearner("classif.gbm", predict.type = "prob")
ps = makeParamSet(
  makeIntegerParam("interaction.depth", lower = 1, upper = 5)
)
ctrl = makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 2, tune.threshold = TRUE)
lrn2 = makeTuneWrapper(lrn1, par.set = ps, control = ctrl, resampling = cv2)
r = resample(lrn2, task, cv3, extract = getTuneResult)
print(r$extract)

[[1]]
Tune result:
Op. pars: interaction.depth=4
Threshold: 0.52
mmce.test.mean=0.0586857

[[2]]
Tune result:
Op. pars: interaction.depth=5
Threshold: 0.54
mmce.test.mean=0.0557573

[[3]]
Tune result:
Op. pars: interaction.depth=5
Threshold: 0.51
mmce.test.mean=0.0514993
```

Here the optimal threshold is 0.51.

I then tried tuning the threshold by using `tuneThreshold` directly on the prediction object:

```
tuneThreshold(r$pred)
$th
[1] 0.5650756

$perf
      mmce 
0.05303195
```

Here the optimal threshold is 0.565. I don't understand why the optimal threshold here is different from the one above, why didn't it return the same threshold as the one found above, i.e. 0.51? It seems to be adding another layer of randomness but I don't know where or how because when I call `tuneThreshold(r$pred)` again, the threshold and performance score do not change. How does `tuneThreshold` work exactly? What does it do with the prediction object `r$pred`?

Answer (score 0):

- Your link referring to CrossValidated is dead
- Always use `set.seed()` for stochastic processes to make them reproducible
- What is the `load_all()` for?

As for your question:

Why would you assume them to be the same? You are doing two completly different things:

- Value 1 is the best threshold that was found during tuning in a CV scenario
- Value 2 is a call from a single prediction object (which stores a different dataset than the ones in the CV)

> when I call tuneThreshold(r$pred) again, the threshold and
>   performance score do not change.

There is no sampling going in this call so the result will always be the same. 
During CV, you have a non-deterministic sampling which changes your datasets in every run - unless you set a seed.

Comment: Thanks @pat-s. I understand where Value 1 comes from but I'm confused specifically about Value 2. The outer CV results in 3 models, each with its own predictions and threshold value, so why does applying `tuneThreshold` to the `ResamplePrediction` object return just a single threshold? `getPredictionProbabilities(r$pred)` similarly also returns a single vector of prediction probabilities - how are these probabilities calculated? Is it just the collection of predicted probabilities over all 3 CV folds?